# Is it possible to use single SCDF server and connect multiple repositories?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I would like to leverage SCDF server and connect to repositories dynamically to schedule/track progress of jobs.

Single SCDF Server 
Repository (dedicated Database) for each tenant

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to running multiple instances of Spring Cloud Data Flow server instances each pointing to its own jobs (based on the database you configured for SCDF and your batch jobs).

While this can be done, you can also have a single Spring Cloud Data Flow server configured to use multiple task platform configurations.

Comment: Can you provide some reference pointers or documentation. 
I'm unable to achieve this. My Deployment is as below 

1. UI Console is same for all customers (assume they are separated by auth)
2. Based on the customer, the DB repository should be connected and respective customers will be able to define their tasks and execute them

Note - https://github.com/bytefish/SpringBootMultiTenancy I'm trying to have similar approach discussed here, which is individual DB per tenant.