# Is it feasible to use one Spring Cloud Dataflow UI for multiple batch applications?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

In the world of microservices, we would have multiple applications that have their own independent datasources and corresponding batch applications in their bounded context. Having this said, since SCDF requires a datasource to be configured to bring it up to monitor batch jobs, is it possible to configure a single, central SCDF server and UI to monitor all the batch jobs of different microservices(obviously with corresponding DBs) with the spring batch metadata tables intact with the applications' business tables? Asking this because it might look very clumsy, untidy and unmaintainable to keep so many SCDF servers running in the environment(Please correct me if my feeling is senseless).

Please bring me some clarity on this query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use single SCDF server and connect multiple repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57387914/is-it-possible-to-use-single-scdf-server-and-connect-multiple-repositories)

Comment: The above link answered it partially. It just confirms "While this can be done, you can also have a single Spring Cloud Data Flow server configured to use multiple task platform configurations." Can you also point me to a reference on how to achieve this?

Comment: Any pointers on this please?

Answer (score 1):

Yes
Setup and install a single SCDF server with an associated DB. For each of your task/batch apps
override the TaskConfigurer and BatchConfigurer to accept a second datasource that refers to SCDF DB as shown here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/tree/main/spring-cloud-task-samples/multiple-datasources.
Thus the batch and task apps will report their state to the SCDF DB while still using their own DB for the work desired.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Glenn. Does this also makes batch related metadata tables to be created and managed in the DB associated to SCDF? If yes, is there a way to keep the batch metadata tables intact with the application's business?

Comment: Yes.
To the second question can you provide a little more detail?

Comment: I mean to ask if there is way to keep the spring batch metadata tables in the db associated with application, not associated with SCDF.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a way to only create spring-cloud related tables in the database of SCDF? I have a spring cloud task which is a batch job application and i have 2 datasources configured, one for the batch workload and one for SCDF. But it creates tables in both databases.

Comment: @Manu For Spring Cloud Task you can look at this sample on using the DefaultTaskConfigurer.   https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/tree/main/spring-cloud-task-samples/multiple-datasources.  And similarly if you are using Batch 4.x then you can use the BatchConfigurer